# JQuery Selected Checkbox Item Background Color

Tags: jquery

I've got the code below "working" but I can't figure out how to get the click event to be just for the checkbox.  Right now just click the li will toggle my background color...I'm totally missing something here.  All I need is that for each li that has a checkbox checked the bg color will change and when unchecked it will return to it's previous color.  Can anyone help me out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.list-item').find('input:checkbox').each(function(index) {
        var selectedlistitem = $('.list-item');
        $(selectedlistitem).click(function () {                     
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        });
    });
});
</script>


<ul> class="list-item-container">
<li class="list-item"><input type="checkbox" />Item 1</li>
<li class="list-item"><input type="checkbox" />Item 2</li>
<li class="list-item"><input type="checkbox" />Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things quite a bit, you just need to do this:

```
$('.list-item :checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.list-item').toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ddkD9/

You don't need `$().find().each()`, you can flatten your `$().find()` into a single selector and jQuery functions are (almost always) set-based already so there's no need for iteration using [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/). Also, `input:checkbox` is redundant, all checkboxes are `<input>`s already so you just need [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) to find checkboxes.

Inside the callback you can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to go back up the DOM from the checkbox, `this`, to find the containing `<li class="list-item">`.

Comment: This is awesome!  Thank you for the answer and demo.  No question about it...I've got a lot to learn. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.list-item input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var selectedlistitem = $(this).parent('li');
    selectedlistitem.toggleClass('selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3s2pk/

You dont need to do the each function, and within each one should refer to the clicked element itself, and not do a global selector.

Comment: If you're using `parent()` you don't need to add a selector as it only travels one level up the DOM tree. You would need it for `parents()`. Also, the `selectedlistitem` variable is not required.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.list-item :checkbox').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected');
});
```